# Why does matplotlib not work on a digitalocean VPS with web2py?

Tags: python, nginx, matplotlib, web2py, digital-ocean

I've got a digitalocean droplet and I deployed web2py using this [script](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/setup-web2py-nginx-uwsgi-ubuntu.sh). I installed matplotlib as follows:

```
ssh root@ipdroplet
apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and I can indeed import `matplotlib` if I simply run `python` on the command line after I've ssh'd. The problem is that when I run my app I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> Cannot import module applications.app.modules.matplotlib
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with user `www-data` vs `root` but no idea how to resolve it. Any help much appreciated. The tips that are mentioned in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/TWgBjFIG1GU/FCHI6KnBcrEJ) link unfortunately didn't help me.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I should also mention that I'm not using the binary version of web2py. I've also managed to run python as `www-data` by doing `sudo -u www-data python` and I can import matplotlib there just fine.

**EDIT2**

When I was running locally on web2py 2.11.2-stable it worked fine. On my server though I was under 2.12.3-stable. I'm guessing this is probably the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution.

Since it wants to find the matplotlib module in the web2py application's module folder I created a symbolic link from there to the actual installation. I then needed to also change the backend as the little [trick](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/TWgBjFIG1GU/FCHI6KnBcrEJ) didn't work.

```
ln -s modules/matplotlib path_to_matplotlib
```

The way I got `path_to_matplotlib` was:

```
~#: python
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib
<module 'matplotlib' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib>/__init__.pyc
>>> print matplotlib.matplotlib_fname() # This will give the path to the backend settings
/etc/matplotlibrc
```

so the link command looks like:

```
ln -s /home/www-data/web2py/applications/app/modules/matplotlib /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib
```

I also needed to change the backend, you get the path as shown above ( `matplotlib_fname()` ). Find the line where it says backend and make sure it is set to `Agg`.

```
backend: Agg
```

usually it's set to `TkAgg`.

Comment: You should report this on the Google Group. Although web2py will first look in the application's "modules" folder, it certainly does not require that all modules be found there -- if not found, it will search the rest of `sys.path`.

Comment: Hm... I've tried in the past posting on the Google group but have failed miserably. If you think it would be useful feel free to post a link to this question and answer. I'll try posting to Google groups but have very low expectations of it working